# Could not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/bin/xdpyinfo. Check if the DISPLAY variable is set. Failed <<<<

Tags: linux, oracle12c

I am getting following error while executing the below command in linux for installing oracle on  EC2 instance.

Any one please help me on this.all valuable suggestions would be appreciated.

```
$./runInstaller
Starting Oracle Universal Installer...

Checking Temp space: must be greater than 500 MB.   Actual 9321 MB    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 150 MB.   Actual 1023 MB    Passed
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors
```

> >>>>Could not execute auto check for display colors using command
>   /usr/bin/xdpyinfo. Check if the DISPLAY variable is set.    Failed
>   <<<<

Some requirement checks failed. You must fulfill these requirements before

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment,I would update this question inboth linux excahange ,DBAdministrator exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read this in the [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47689/app_ts.htm#LADBI0123) :

> This can occur if the DISPLAY variable is not set, or the user running
>   the installation is not authorized to open an X window. For instance,
>   if you use an su command to change from a user that is authorized to
>   open an X window to a user account that is not authorized to open an X
>   window on the display, such as a lower-privileged user opening windows
>   on the root user's console display.
>
> **To troubleshoot this issue**, run the command echo $DISPLAY to ensure
>   that the display variable is set to the correct visual or to the
>   correct host. If the display variable is set correctly then either
>   ensure that you are logged in as the user authorized to open an X
>   window, or **run the command xhost + to allow any user to open an X**
>   **window**.

Answer (score 2):

```
# xhost +SI:localuser:oracle

$ ./runInstaller
```

this work fine in my case

Comment: Can you add some explainations?

Comment: sory I don't have any. I was facing same error. I  google it, follow these step and get resolve error.

Comment: maybe you meant this 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97665_01/html/rpm_81_installation_11g/GUID-842C3883-9BC1-4D37-82C1-9E7F24628AA7.htm

In some cases it is required to download utils manually. If it is not working after this try seting $DISPLAY

Answer (score 2):

login to oracle user

```
# su - oracle
```

run this command

```
$ export DISPLAY=':0'
```

and run the ./runInstaller

Answer (score 0):

run with `root` user (not sure if this step is mandatory):

```
xhost +
```

then switch to oracle user and set display

```
su - oracle
export DISPLAY=yourHostName:1
```